# Is it a good design to put all the testclasses of subclasses of the command interface (See command pattern) in one file

Tags: java, design-patterns, testing, junit

I have a command interface with only one function:

```
public <T> boolean isValid(Class<? extends T> subType,
        Class<? extends T> superType);
```

For this interface I have several implementations (let's say four or five). Is it a good idea to put the testcases of all these implementations in one test class?

Comment: I'd keep them separate but it purely a personal thing I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is better to keep test classes separate.

The more separate test classes are, the easier is to maintain changes. E.g. in time you could add new functionalities to particular classes and your test class will be bigger and bigger.

I saw once test class with if-statements which had 1500 lines of code!.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good programming practice to keep all your test is different classes but same package(which is different than your main package).

If in future you wish to change your main code and test class changes accordingly it will be easy for you to integrate your changes.

Another important reason is when you build your projects you can provide option to run test cases in the build process. The build will fail if your test cases fail. Keeping test functions for different main classes in different test classes will help you figure out what went wrong in case the build fails due to test cases failures.